# C#, my code jumps over my if statement inside the try-catch statement

Tags: c#

When I type "done" it doesn't add the numbers and shows the results. It just skips over the "if" statement right to the "catch" statement. I have already tried putting the "if" statement in different places but I couldn't do it because the "result" is inside of the "try" statement. Please help.
It's supposed to be like this: When I type a number(5), then "enter", then another number(5.3), then "enter" again, it's supposed to show the result which should be "10.3"(5 + 5.3 = 10.3). Really sorry for the long text, I appreciate any help.

```
        while (true)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number or type \"done\" to see the average: ");
            var input = Console.ReadLine();

            try
            {
                var result = double.Parse(input);
                if(input == "done")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(result += result);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                        continue;
                }
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("That is not valid input.");
            }
```

Comment: If it never hits the if statement, then something before it is causing an exception, which is what is being caught. If the input is "done", then how do you expect that to become a double?

Comment: You try to parse input into a double _before_ checking if it's equal to "done". This means that if user enter "done" you have an exception and therefore  code within the if will never execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is incorrect: `"done"` has *no chance* to be *parsed* into `double`. You have to check for `"done"` *first*:

```
    // since you want to aggregate within the loop, you have to declare sum 
    // without the loop  
    double sum = 0.0;

    while (true)
    {
        //DONE: You're summing up, right? It'll be sum, not average
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number or type \"done\" to see the sum: ");

        var input = Console.ReadLine();

        if (input == "done") 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sum);
            break;
        }

        try
        {
            sum += double.Parse(input);
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("That is not valid input.");
        }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping! I am new and self taught in C#, that's why I asked such a dumb question. I see what I did wrong now. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You're parsing the "done" to the double data type and that's why the formatException is raised.